# Is it possible to append to an xarray.Dataset?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, python-xarray

I've been using the `.append()` method to concatenate two tables (with the same fields) in pandas. Unfortunately this method does not exist in `xarray`, is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Xarray doesn't have an append method because its data structures are built on top of NumPy's non-resizable arrays, so we cannot append new elements without copying the entire array. Hence, we don't implement an `append` method. Instead, you should use [`xarray.concat`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.concat.html#xarray.concat).

One usual pattern is to accumulate Dataset/DataArray objects in a list, and concatenate once at the end:

```
datasets = []
for example in examples:
    ds = create_an_xarray_dataset(example)
    datasets.append(ds)
combined = xarray.concat(datasets, dim='example')
```

You don't want to concatenate inside the loop -- that would make your code run in quadratic time.

Alternatively, you could allocate a single Dataset/DataArray for the result, and 
[fill in the values with indexing](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/indexing.html#assigning-values-with-indexing), e.g.,

```
dims = ('example', 'x', 'y')
combined = xarray.Dataset(
    data_vars={'my_variable': (dims, np.zeros((len(examples), 100, 200)))},
    coords={'example': examples})
for example in examples:
    combined.loc[dict(example=example)] = create_an_xarray_dataset(example)
```

(Note that you always need to use indexing with square brackets like `[]` or `.loc[]` -- assigning with `sel()` and `isel()` doesn't work.)

These two approaches are equally efficient -- it's really a matter of taste which one looks better to you or works better for your application.

For what it's worth, pandas has the same limitation: the `append` method does indeed copy entire dataframes each time it is used. This is a perpetual surprise and source of performance issues for new users. So I do think that we made the right design decision not including it in xarray.

Answer (score 2):

You can either use `.concat` or  `merge()`. [Documentation](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/combining.html).