# xarray appending or rewriting a existing nc file

Tags: url-rewriting, append, netcdf, python-xarray

Can xarray append or rewrite an existing NetCDF file? I need to update my data (NetCDF format) every year. I want to rewrite or append an existing NetCDF file by using xarray. However, I need to read all data into the memory and concatenate them, then overwrite the NC file. It consumes too much memory and less efficient. Is there any possibility that rewrites the file just like python library of NETCDF4?

Answer (score 1):

The xarray documentation here:
https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/io.html#reading-and-writing-files

States the following:

> It is possible to append or overwrite netCDF variables using the
> mode='a' argument. When using this option, all variables in the
> dataset will be written to the original netCDF file, regardless if
> they exist in the original dataset.

You can add a new variable, but you cannot add data to an existing variable without re-creating it.

See also this (duplicate) question: [Is it possible to append to an xarray.Dataset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33435953/is-it-possible-to-append-to-an-xarray-dataset)

It's from a few years back, but things haven't changed. Unfortunately, you'd have to use the netCDF4 package directly instead.

Comment: The linked question isn’t about appending to a netcdf file, it’s about appending to an in-memory xr.Dataset. So it’s not a duplicate.